# ProviderName= Npgsql not working on Azure

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, azure, connection-string

I have a test my webapi on local machine and it is working but on azure it is not working, for azure is there something more I need to do?

I try this:

```
public Context() : base("name=DefaultConnectionString")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
}
```

where my connectionString is:

```
<add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="host=HOST;SSL Mode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Port=5432;Database=DB;" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

And I try set the provider name by code like:

```
var providerName = "Npgsql";
var conn = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName).CreateConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = $"Host={host}; " + $"Port={port}; " +
                $"User Id={userName};" + $"Password={password};" + $"Database={databaseName}; SSL Mode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true;";

            return conn;
```

My provider:

```
 <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, My ip on azure is not working, so a change my ip for `start:0.0.0.0` and `end:255.255.255.255`, and it is working... now i am search for a better solution